# how to map custom domain on google app engine with wordpress

Tags: wordpress, google-app-engine

my domain in godaddy and my wordpress website is hosted in google app engine.
but i cant open my wordpress install link with domain name

for example:
http://www.example.com/wp-admin/install.php

if i run the below link then its working but when i run with domain it's not work.

http://example-wp.appspot.com/wp-admin/install.php

Comment: Have you tried following these steps: https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/appengine-php-wordpress-starter-project/

Comment: yes but in this link there is dns maping steps are available.

Comment: Have you followed the instructions to configure your domain to point to your app engine project? https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/using-custom-domains-and-ssl